# Bundled iOS app using two IPAs

Tags: ios, ios6

I am exploring into the possibility of creating a bundled app out of TWO of my apps (app1.ipa & app2.ipa).  Is it possible to create a shell app (bundle.ipa) which would load app1 or app2 using their respective ipa’s (app1.ipa or app2.ipa) based on user selection? Or Do I have to merge the source codes and assets on both apps to create a bundled app? Basically, is it possible to load an ipa with-in an ipa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible to create apps with more then one binary.

Comment: Thanks Bastian. That's what I knew but wanted to validate it to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to have more than one .ipa - which I'm pretty sure isn't possible - creating a class by which the app can introspect whether or not the person has paid for the app. So if they have, the feature is available, and if not... its not available.

Use Facebook's SDK integration as a reference of how this works: before an app can retrieve items from the user's Facebook, the app must make sure that the user has signed in with Facebook.

I wish I knew of a more precise example, but honestly, this should give you the gist of it all.